# SMPS turning ON from earth flowing back into GND output

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, grounding

I've got a problem with a design using a SMPS.

- The input is AC phase and neutral, one wire going through a power switch.
- The output is 12V DC with the GND wired to the AC's earth.

The issue is that when the neutral (or phase) is cut OFF, the SMPS turns ON briefly for 0.5 seconds every 20 seconds (outputs enough current to move a cooling fan and a relay).

My guess is that there is some kind of coupling inside the SMPS because the GND output is wired to the main's earth and either the neutral or phase on the SMPS input and it's charging a capacitor somewhere to the level at which the SMPS turns ON by itself.

Is that an expected issue? I would like to avoid using a diode at the output (which would defeat the purpose of earthing the ground and mess with the levels). If anyone has an idea, it would be great help! I'm going to reverse-engineer the SMPS but if someone has a simple fix, I'll gladly take it!

Notes:

- I have to wire the GND to earth to avoid some audio amp buzzing when someone touches some volume knobs/pots found later in the power-path.
- Phase and neutral can be swapped depending on how the user plugs it/wall outlet wiring so I cannot control if either the phase or neutral is cut by the power switch.
- The power switch is only for one wire (because, yes, it would be much easier to have a switch that cuts off both phase and neutral but I can't change this at this point).
- The SMPS is a unknown brand, I didn't reverse-engineer it yet.

Thank you for your input!

[image: The SMPS or Similar]

Edit: The question was deleted due to lack of clarity. I've got a perfectly fine answer from one member and it was indeed the issue and solved the problem I had. So no, this question do not lack clarity.

Comment: Reverse engineering an unknown brand means that any design issues or oddities associated with that unknown brand get perpetuated. Just cause you reverse engineer something that you might sell doesn't mean there is any recognizable design authority and you cannot claim any significant quality levels about said design. Reverse engineering something with a known undesirable quality makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Many SMPS have similar design so some other people may have encountered a similar issue and found a fix. Btw: The one I've got to work with is performing quite well. AFAIK It was picked amongst several samples for its low noise, stability and features, it's not the horrible led driver kind. But yeah, I get your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all cheap LED lamps did this when they got to market. The problem is leakage current caused by capacitive coupling between wires, so AC voltage will gradually pump up charge to SMPS input cap until voltage is enough for the SMPS to start and the cap will the discharge quickly.

I do not recommend modifying these yourself, unless you know what you are doing and can use suitable components rated appropriately for the job. In theory, there should be something like a 1 Mohm of resistance at the mains input, or maybe at the main input capacitor, to have enough load on it so the capacitive coupling can't charge the input capacitor. In real life, and depending on what is your local mains AC voltage and your local regulations about safety, one single resistor is typically not enough.

Simply put, if you can'y change the switch, change the SMPS to one that works. Make sure you get one that is meant to be used with live and neutral only, i.e. make sure your SMPS does not require earth to operate normally and safely if you don't have earth.

Comment: Yes, the big input capacitor (after full bridge rectifier) charges slowly. I've put a 220K resistor at the capacitor to fix the issue, but that's nearly 0.5W of waste during operation, close to unreasonable, I'll look for some additional workarounds.

Comment: I just noticed that since you have an unpolarized plug, doesn't that require for safety reasons that both live and neutral must be switched, not just one? And if the SMPS is meant to be used with two prong mains, do you know if it is meant to have outside world connections at all, or used inside a lamp where it can't be touched? Which would also mean the output may not be intended to be earthed, as there is a clear capacitive path between output ground and mains side, via the blue EMI suppression cap right below the transformer. Make sure you have bought a power supply for your application.

Comment: The plug is polarized but some wall outlets are wrongly wired in some houses, this caused the problem. There is no outside connection at all, but we found out sensitive equipment such as audio amp do not like to have the GND floating so we did connect GND to Earth.